# Simple jQuery Parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reload, parallax

I need help debugging this jQuery, wherein I manipulate the top margin of an element in a container with a fixed size and overflow set to hidden, so that I can create the parallax effect. The parallax works, but if you scroll down even a single pixel, and then reload the page, it breaks. Can anyone help me fix that issue? Here's the code.

```
//Parallax for Header
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var startingScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
    console.log(startingScrollTop);
    var startingElementTop = parseInt($headerText.css("margin-top"));
    console.log(startingElementTop);
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var currentScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
        console.log(currentScrollTop);
        if(currentScrollTop > startingScrollTop) {
            var scrollDistance = currentScrollTop - startingScrollTop;
            console.log(scrollDistance);
            var parallaxDistance = scrollDistance / 2;
            console.log(parallaxDistance);
            var newElementMarginTop = startingElementTop + parallaxDistance;
            console.log(newElementMarginTop);
            $headerText.css("margin-top", newElementMarginTop + "px");
        } else if(currentScrollTop <= "0") {
            $headerText.css("margin-top", "0px");
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You need to detect the current position before you run your scroll. Thats why it breaks. You need to add conditions that check where it currently is. Since you are using a Fixed Position, it will move with the scroll bar, but its top position still changes. Unless you check that top position first and then write your if statements of if top > 0 do this followed by your else statement.

Comment: Also a fiddle for this would be really helpful as well.

Comment: I actually think you should just make your ```startingScrollTop = 0```. When you reload a page, the browser automatically scrolls to your last location by default, and causes your start location to reflect that. If you've scrolled all the way down the page, then you won't get any animation at all after you refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but how can I simplify this?

```
//Parallax for Header
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var startingScrollTop = 0;
  console.log(startingScrollTop);
  var startingElementTop = parseInt($headerText.css("margin-top"));
  console.log(startingElementTop);
  //Re-use this on scroll
  var currentScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
  console.log(currentScrollTop);
  if(currentScrollTop > startingScrollTop) {
    var scrollDistance = currentScrollTop - startingScrollTop;
    console.log(scrollDistance);
    var parallaxDistance = scrollDistance / 2;
    console.log(parallaxDistance);
    var newElementMarginTop = startingElementTop + parallaxDistance;
    console.log(newElementMarginTop);
    $headerText.css("margin-top", newElementMarginTop + "px");
  } else if(currentScrollTop <= "0") {
    $headerText.css("margin-top", "0px");
  }
  //Put the re-used code here
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var currentScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
    console.log(currentScrollTop);
    if(currentScrollTop > startingScrollTop) {
      var scrollDistance = currentScrollTop - startingScrollTop;
      console.log(scrollDistance);
      var parallaxDistance = scrollDistance / 2;
      console.log(parallaxDistance);
      var newElementMarginTop = startingElementTop + parallaxDistance;
      console.log(newElementMarginTop);
      $headerText.css("margin-top", newElementMarginTop + "px");
    } else if(currentScrollTop <= "0") {
      $headerText.css("margin-top", "0px");
    }
  });
});
```

Can I turn the re-used code into a function that I can run on load, scroll, or on any other handler?

Answer (score 0):

Once again, never mind, I pulled it off:

for all those who desire:

```
//Parallax for Header
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var startingScrollTop = 0;
  console.log(startingScrollTop);
  var startingElementTop = parseInt($headerText.css("margin-top"));
  console.log(startingElementTop);
  //Re-use this on scroll
  function parallaxify() {
    var currentScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
    console.log(currentScrollTop);
    if(currentScrollTop > startingScrollTop) {
      var scrollDistance = currentScrollTop - startingScrollTop;
      console.log(scrollDistance);
      var parallaxDistance = scrollDistance / 2;
      console.log(parallaxDistance);
      var newElementMarginTop = startingElementTop + parallaxDistance;
      console.log(newElementMarginTop);
      $headerText.css("margin-top", newElementMarginTop + "px");
    } else if(currentScrollTop <= "0") {
      $headerText.css("margin-top", "0px");
    }
  }
  parallaxify();
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    //Put the re-used code here
    parallaxify();
  });
});
```